# É possível anexar um arquivo do res/drawable do Android em um email, utilizando JavaMail?

Tags: android, javamail, resources, drawable

Estou buscando a solução de duas formas:

- **Obter o PATH de arquivo:**

Gostaria obter o `path` de uma imagem que esta em `res/drawable` em meu projeto Android.

Estou necessitando do `path` porque tenho que enviar ele em anexo por e-mail, e estou utilizando [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) para isso e ele somente aceita um `path` ou um `File`, para arquivo em anexo.

- **Fazer com que o JavaMail consiga aceitar um Bitmap:**

Alterar forma de criação do anexo do email, hoje estou fazendo assim:

```java
MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
// aqui teria que setar um bitmap ao inves de um Path ou File;
attachmentPart.attachFile(attachment);
attachmentPart.setContentID("<image>");
attachmentPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
content.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
```

**Vou tentar explicar um pouco melhor o problema:**

Estou necessitando disso para se não achar um logo configurado pelo usuário (em uma pasta especifica e com nome especifico no sdcard) para assinatura de email, então utilizaria um logo padrão de minha aplicação, e esse logo padrão está disponível em meus resources (res/drawable), já que ele é imutável.

> Vi a solução que o @ramaral postou, mas apesar de boa, não é uma solução que eu esperava, acredito que deve haver outra forma, pois ter que fazer uma copia da imagem para o sdcard. não me parece "cheirar bem".

**Solução Final com auxilia das respostas citadas**

Utilizando o [ByteArrayDataSource](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html#ByteArrayDataSource%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) como citado por [@Elcio Arthur Cardoso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5787/elcio-arthur-cardoso) em sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10068/e-possivel-anexar-um-arquivo-do-res-drawable-do-android-em-um-email-utilizando/17549#17549), troquei meu método que inclui o anexo para permitir anexar um arquivo em `byte[]` assim:

```java
MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart();

// ... add message part

// converter bitmap to byte[]
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.transparent_1x1);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageBytes = stream.toByteArray();

// criar anexo do email, apartir de um array de byte (byte[])
MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataHandler handlerAttach = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(imageBytes));
attachmentPart.setDataHandler(handlerAttach);
attachmentPart.setFileName("image.png");
attachmentPart.setContentID("<image>");
attachmentPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
content.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
```

Essa solução funcionou perfeitamente para o meu caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve ler o arquivo da forma como o [@ramaral falou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10068/e-possivel-anexar-um-arquivo-do-res-drawable-do-android-em-um-email-utilizando/10085#10085):

```c#
Resources resources= getResources();
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.image);
```

mas no lugar de gravar no SDCard, você pode anexar direto utilizando o [ByteArrayDataSource](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html#ByteArrayDataSource%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) do JavaMail.

Esses links (em inglês) devem ajudar:

- [Send Email Attachement using byte[] with Java-Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804901/send-email-attachement-using-byte-with-java-mail)
- [Sending Emails with Attachments Using JavaMail](http://www.sivalabs.in/2011/05/sending-email-with-attachments-using.html)

Comment: Estou testando sua solução.

Comment: Solucionei a a partir de sua resposta, e postei em minha pergunta a solução final, se desejar adicionar a solução a sua resposta para ficar mais claro para futuras pesquisas fique a vontade. Ou se tiver alguma melhoria, por favor compartilhe. Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Você não consegue, de forma directa, aceder ao caminho nem ficheiro porque os `resources` são compilados junto com a aplicação.

O que se pode fazer é criar um Bitmap a partir do `resource`.

```
Resources resources= getResources();
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.image);
```

O `Bitmap` pode ser gravado no `SdCard`, depois já pode enviá-lo por email. Veja [aqui](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/android-tutorial-save-bitmap-image-on-android-sd-card/) como gravar.

Comment: mais mesmo assim a partir de um `Bitmap` eu não consigo obter nem o `path` nem o `File`, para poder setar meu Anexo. Ou há alguma maneira?

Comment: O `Bitmap` pode ser gravado no `SdCard`. Veja [aqui](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/android-tutorial-save-bitmap-image-on-android-sd-card/) como fazer

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui solucionar, a partir de suas dicas e dos colegas, confira minha solução e se tiver dicas para melhorias, sinta-se a vontade para edita-la.

Answer (score 3):

Pesquisando, achei uma solução que não pude testar porque não estou em casa...

A princípio, é possível acessar o drawable do seu app com uma URI com protocolo `android.resource`.

Para acessar um drawable através do `File` seria:

```
File image = new File("android.resource://package_do_app/"+ R.drawable.image);
```

Como eu disse anteriormente, não pude testar, se o código não funcionar eu deleto a resposta. Se estou infringindo alguma regra do SO, peço desculpas antecipadamente.

A fonte é esta pergunta do [SO Oficial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879098/android-how-to-get-the-path-name-of-the-drawable).
Uma outra fonte com mais [detalhes](http://androidbook.blogspot.in/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html).

## Pelo que foi constatado, a forma acima não é uniforme para todas as versões do Android.

Logo, analisando a documentação do `MimeBodyPart` do JavaMail, existe um Construtor que recebe um `InputStream`, e como no Android é possível obter um `InputStream` a partir de um `Drawable` que se localiza estritamente na pasta **`raw`**.

Para recuperar um `InputStream` a partir de um `Drawable` que está na pasta **`resource/raw`** eu faço desta maneira:

```
public class AssetsHelper {
    public static InputStream readRawResource(Context context, int rawResId) {
        return context.getResources().openRawResource(rawResId);
    }
}
```

A partir do seu código, eu faria algo como:

```
MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart(AssetsHelper.readRawResource(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.transparent1x1);
//... Restante do código
```

Colocando a sua imagem no `res/raw` deve funcionar.

Comment: Irei testar aqui e retornarei, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Isso não funcionou aqui para mim. Gerou `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.resource:/com.catalogo.app/2130837562: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Para cria o `File` fiz o seguinte: `file = new File(String.format("android.resource://%s/%s", this.getPackageName(), R.drawable.transparent1x1));`, depois dei um `.getAbsolutePath()` para obter a `URI`. Por que não funcionou para mim?

Comment: Eu posso testar mais tarde, mas olhando o segundo link, acho que cometi um erro, talvez precise colocar o tipo de resource no path. Tipo: `File image = new File("android.resource://package_do_app/drawable/"+ R.drawable.image);`. É como eu disse, não testei ainda, posso fazer isso mais a noite.

Comment: @Fernando, irei fazer uns testes para aprimorar minha resposta.

Comment: Eu testei a resposta do @Wakim e funcionou para mim. Se deu FileNotFoundException, você tem certeza que transparent1x1 está na sua pasta drawable?

Comment: Acho que isso varia de versão para versão, testei com um kitkat e não funcionou... @Fernando, olhando a documentação do `MimeBodyPart`, me parece que ele dá pra fazer, mas de uma forma diferente da que eu citei... Vou preparar um código aqui e coloco aqui na resposta...

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui solucionar, a partir de suas dicas e dos colegas, confira minha solução e se tiver dicas para melhorias, sinta-se a vontade para edita-la.